# Recursive coin change c++

Tags: c++, recursion, coin-change

My program seems to be crashing every time it recursive calling in the minimum function. Can anyone tell me why it is crashing. It would instantly freeze after i call the minimum function. Is it because im using a vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int minimum(vector<int> denom, int s, int N) //take in denomination , sizeofcoin, and value of N
{
    if(N == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(N < 0 || (N > 0 && s <=0))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return min(minimum(denom,s - 1, N), 1 + minimum(denom, s,N-denom[s-1]));
    }
}
int main()
{
    int N;
    unsigned int sizeofcoin;
    cout << "Enter the value N to produce: " << endl;
    cin >> N;
    cout << "Enter the number of different denominations: " << endl;
    cin >> sizeofcoin;

    vector<int> denom(sizeofcoin);
    for(unsigned int i= 0; i < sizeofcoin; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter denomination #" << (i+1) << endl;          //save all the denominations in an array
        cin >> denom[i];
    }

    sort(denom.begin() , denom.end(),greater<int>());    //sort the array from largest to smallest
    if(denom.back() != 1)                                 //check the end of the array (since the back is smallest now) if it has 1
    {
        denom.push_back(1);                             //Will include 1 if the user does not input a 1 (doesn't have to be used)
    }
    minimum(denom,sizeofcoin,N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can any1 help me i tried almost everything for recursive but i don't seem to understand what is is suppose to be doing ?

Answer (score 5):

I tried to [explain your `minimum()` function to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and your rubber duck has a question for you. Here's how our conversation went:

```
int minimum(vector<int> denom, int s, int N) //take in denomination , sizeofcoin, and value of N
{
    if(N <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

**Me**: this `minimum()` recursive function immediately returns if its third parameter, `N`, is 0, or negative.

**Your Rubber Duck**: Ok.

```
    return (minimum(denom,s - 1, N)...
```

(Here, I tried explaining your first recursion call here, to your rubber duck):

**Me**: So, this makes a recursive call, with the same parameters, except that the 2nd parameter is decremented. The third parameter is `N`.

**Your Rubber Duck**: So, if the third parameter's value, `N`, is unchanged, and the recursive function returns without recursing only when `N` is 0 or negative, and the initial call to `minimum()` passes a value greater than 0 for `N`, then when exactly do you expect this recursion to stop?

I couldn't answer this question myself, maybe you can explain this to your rubber duck, by yourself. When does recursion stop, here?

Answer (score 1):

You have the recursive call `minimum(denom,s - 1, N)` so `N` will *never* be less than or equal to `0`, and the recursion will never end.

This would have been very easy to find out if you learned how to use a debugger, and stepped through the code line by line, and stepped into the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that I want to point out is that you are trying to return the sum of two values:

```
(minimum(denom,s - 1, N) + minimum(denom, s,N-denom[s-1])
```

instead what you should do is:

```
min(minimum(denom,s - 1, N), 1 + minimum(denom, s,N-denom[s-1]))
```

The idea is that in first call you've not used any coin but in second call you have used one, so adding 1 for the same.

Look for a Dynamic Programming solution for the same.
https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~bcdean/dp_practice/